# Negating match if a string is just before another string

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I'm struggling to get a regex to work where it matches a certain pattern, so long as isn't proceeded by another. For example,

```
Accessory for MyProduct01 <<< Should be classified as an accessory
MyProduct01 with accessory << Should be classified as a product
```

So I need to add something to my 'accessory' regex, something like 'match "accessory" so long as the word before isn't "with"'.

I have seen some examples where people are using negative lookaheads to find if a word is anywhere in the string, but I want to be a bit more specific regarding the position of the word to negate. Something like:

```
(?!with\s)accessory
```

Comment: That's not a negative lookbehind; it's a negative look __ahead__  :)

Comment: Precisely: I think you want (?<!with\s)accessory.
As you might guess from the sequence (?<! , this kind of thing originated in perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a negative look-behind in your regex:

```
(?<!with\s)accessory
```

Comment: This worked, even in python. However, I made a mistake that I am actually using search not match, although I'm not sure if that would have an impact. This also worked, for anyone else who might be interested.
((?<!with\s)|(?<!including\s))accessory

Comment: This regex can be used fir both search and match. The key point us that look-behinds need to have a bounded length (you can't use `*` or `+` etc).

Comment: Btw the regex in your comment doesn't make sense: the ORed look-behind expression is *always* true! Just have two, like this `(?<!with\s)(?<!including\s)accessories`

Answer (score 0):

Since Python doesn't support unbounded lookbehinds, I think you are going to have to use a lookahead similar to what you are currently using, but change the original pattern a bit.

```
^(?!\bwith\b.*\baccessory\b)(?=.*\b(accessory)\b)
```

Here, the negative lookahead is used to ensure that "accessory" doesn't come after the word "with". Then, the positive lookahead is used to ensure that the word "accessory" occurs within the string, captured with a group if you need to capture it for some reason.

Based on the way that I wrote the above, you'd want to use the `search` method and not the `match` method. In order to use `match`, which requires that the entire search string match the pattern, you'd need to add a bit more to the pattern:

```
^(?!\bwith\b.*\baccessory\b)(?=.*\b(accessory)\b).*$
```